# Why does starting openvpn client, then dhcpcd give different routing table than the reverse order?

Tags: vpn, dhcp

I am connecting through a router in my home, and tunneling all traffic via openvpn through a remote server. When I first connect with dhcpcd, then start openvpn, my routes look like this (on a linux machine)

```
$ ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0  metric 303 
10.8.0.1 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.2 
<my.vpn.server's.ip> via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp4s0  proto kernel  scope link  src    192.168.1.114  metric 303
```

however, if I then restart the dhcpcd service, the routes look like this

```
$ ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0  metric 303 
10.8.0.1 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.2 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp4s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.114  metric 303
```

With the difference being that this line is no longer present

```
<my.vpn.server's.ip> via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0
```

the result of which is that I can no longer access the internet. What is the significance of that line, and why would restarting dhcpcd remove it?

note that my openvpn client config contains

```
        remote <my.vpn.server's.hostname>
        dev tun0
        ifconfig 10.8.0.2 10.8.0.1
        secret /root/static.key
        mtu-test
        redirect-gateway def1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is with the routes in your routing table after you start the VPN tunnel and before you restart dhcpd:

```
$ ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0  metric 303 
10.8.0.1 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.2 
<my.vpn.server's.ip> via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp4s0  proto kernel  scope link  src    192.168.1.114  metric 303
```

You have two default routes. Firstly you will presumably be receiving one via DHCP from your home router, this one: `default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0  metric 303`. That allows you to access the  Internet without the VPN (otherwise how will your Linux machine know which path to take to connect to the far end of your VPN tunnel).

You also have a 2nd default route which is presumably being installed by openvpn when you establish the VPN tunnel, this one: `0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0` (technically speaking that isn't quite a default route, it should be 0.0.0.0/0)

Note that the `default via 192...` route has a metric of 303 so it will be less preferred than the default route via the tunnel. This causes a problem though:

1. The preferred default route results in all traffic being forced to be sent via 10.0.8.1 which is connected to interface tun0
2. tun0 is a logical interface not a physical interface, that connects to your remote VPN peer
3. To reach your remote VPN peer (10.18.0.1) you need to make a connection outside of your local subnet (192.168.1.0/24 on dev wlp4s0)
4. Without a more specific route to your remote peer you will use the default route with the lowest metric which is the route `0.0.0.0/1...` so you will go back to step 1 in an infinite loop

It seems your openvpn clients also inserts the following route: `<my.vpn.server's.ip> via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0`

So now all traffic is routed via the default route which points to the vpn tunnel, a second look up is then performed to see that the far end of the VPN `<my.vpn.server's.ip>` is reachable by 192.168.1.1 which is presumably your router. Traffic (in theory) should be sent into tun0 which will then be encrypted and sent towards the router to reach the VPN far end. That is all fine and well.

Now we have set the scene, without seeing your dhcpd and router config I would hazard a guess and say that dhcpd flushes your routing table so that important extra route installed by openvpn is cleared out and you go to a state of infinite recursion I described with the numbered steps 1 to 4 above.

Answer (score 1):

Your VPN host route is destroyed every time dhcp resets the interface. I.e. when 192.168.1.114 (your dhcp assigned address) is removed, all routes to 192.168.1.0/24 will be cleared.

Either your dhcp setup needs to be taught to deal with this (add the route back), or your VPN needs to be reset anytime the interface resets.